# XEN dom0 network Bridge has no connection to domU's

Tags: linux, networking, bridge, xen

I am using Debian wheezy with XEN 4.1. I have two network bridges xenbr0 and xenbr1.

xenbr0 is linked to the real-eth0-nic so the domU's can talk to the outside world, which worked fine.

xenbr1 was intended as an internal network bridge for communication between domU's and dom0.

**The Problem is the xenbr1 and I don't know why.** 
The domU's are successfully connected to the xenbr1 because I can Ping between the domU's. So the bridge is working somehow, but no traffic to or from dom0's xenbr1 is possible.

My xenbr1 setup in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto xenbr1
iface xenbr1 inet static
        pre-up brctl addbr $IFACE
        up ip link set $IFACE up
        post-down brctl delbr $IFACE
        down ip link set $IFACE down
        address         10.0.0.1
        netmask         255.255.255.0
        hwaddress       ether MAC
```

brctl show:

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
xenbr0          8000.mac                no              eth0
                                                        vif1.0
                                                        vif2.0
xenbr1          8000.mac                no              vif1.1
                                                        vif2.1
```

Network connections:

```
                  dom0
            xenbr1 - 10.0.0.1
            /               \
           /                 \
        domU-1              domU-2
  vif1.1 - 10.0.0.2      vif2.1 - 10.0.0.3
```

*domU-1 can ping domU-2 and vice versa.

dom0 can not reach any domU and the domU's can not reach dom0.* So something is blocked in dom0 I think.

My first thought was, that I maybe have a problem with iptables, but it seems that xen created the necessary rules:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-out vif2.1 --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in vif2.1 --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-out vif2.0 --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in vif2.0 --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-out vif1.1 --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in vif1.1 --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-out vif1.0 --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in vif1.0 --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT
```

I hope anyone can help me or has a start where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you actually need an interface other than a bridge on the Lonux dom0 in order for traffic to actually reach dom0.  The bridge is just a bridge, and does not provide an interface into dom0.  You can try setting up a dummy interface in dom0 and adding that to the bridge, or perhaps a tap interface.  I'm not certain this is what's going on, but it is definitely wor a try.